# Custom Post Type Archive Page showing as 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

So I have used the CPT plugin to create a custom post type called Works. The slug I have set is proctor-work and I have created a template called archive-proctor-work.php. I cannot get this to show on http://proctordevelop.wpengine.com/proctor-work, it just keeps showing the 404 page. I have flushed permalinks. All of the files referenced in the archive page have been added to the site in the child theme.

I also have added a registration to functions.php. (see below)
Can anyone help?

here is the code for the archive page:

```php
<?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying Our Work
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
     *
     */
    
    get_header();
    ?>
    
        <section id="primary" class="content-area post-listing -listing">
            <main id="main" class="site-main">
    
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                
    
                <?php include 'our-work-filters.php'; ?>
    
                <div class="center container">
                <?php
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();
    
                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'proctor_content', get_post_type() );
    
                endwhile;
            ?>
                <!-- <div class="pagination"><?php wpex_pagination(); ?></div> -->
            <?php
            else :
    
                get_template_part( 'proctor_content', 'none' );
    
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
            </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
    
    <?php
    get_footer();
```

Registration code

```php
function wporg_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type('proctor-work',
        array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => __( 'Works', 'textdomain' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Work', 'textdomain' ),
            ),
            'public'      => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'proctor-work' ), // my custom slug
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While registering custom_post_type use this parameters too.

'publicly_queryable'    => true,

Then it should be look like this.

```
function wporg_custom_post_type() {
register_post_type('proctor-work',
    array(
        'labels'      => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Works', 'textdomain' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Work', 'textdomain' ),
        ),
        'public'      => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'proctor-work' ), // my custom slug
        'publicly_queryable'    => true
    )
);
```

}